# Map scikit scaled data back to ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` that looks like that:

```
In [48]: df
Out[48]: 
        AMID         A         B         C
0  AMID-1000  0.149176  0.768200  0.689369
1  AMID-1001  0.169934  0.607390  0.471788
2  AMID-1002  0.632052  0.806657  0.994664
3  AMID-1003  0.003798  0.382427  0.894856
4  AMID-1004  0.182947  0.712373  0.870068
5  AMID-1005  0.385039  0.691643  0.546960
6  AMID-1006  0.971885  0.169759  0.804370
7  AMID-1007  0.443199  0.686212  0.377556
8  AMID-1008  0.149402  0.981370  0.588750
9  AMID-1009  0.214107  0.264285  0.463403
```

Column `'AMID'` holds the datapoint id's and each one of the rest of the columns is a feature of each one of the datapoints.

I want to use this dataset with an algorithm that requires that the data is scaled, so that for each column I have `mean == 0` and `std == 1`. I'm using `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` for this, however, in order to scale I need to rid the dataset of the non-numerical `'AMID'` column.

```
In [61]: from sklearn import preprocessing

In [62]: data = df[[_ for _ in df.columns.values.tolist() if _ not in ['AMID']]]

In [64]: scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(data)

In [65]: data_scaled = scaler.transform(data)

In [66]: data_scaled
Out[66]: 
array([[ -6.60180258e-01,   6.63739262e-01,   9.55187160e-02],
       [ -5.84458777e-01,   1.47534202e-03,  -9.87448200e-01],
       [  1.10128130e+00,   8.22117198e-01,   1.61505880e+00],
       [ -1.19049913e+00,  -9.24989864e-01,   1.11828380e+00],
       [ -5.36991596e-01,   4.33827828e-01,   9.94906952e-01],
       [  2.00212895e-01,   3.48454485e-01,  -6.13293011e-01],
       [  2.34094244e+00,  -1.80081691e+00,   6.67913149e-01],
       [  4.12372276e-01,   3.26087187e-01,  -1.45646800e+00],
       [ -6.59357873e-01,   1.54163661e+00,  -4.05292050e-01],
       [ -4.23321269e-01,  -1.41153114e+00,  -1.02918017e+00]])

In [67]: data_scaled.mean(axis=0)
Out[67]: array([ -8.32667268e-17,  -4.44089210e-17,  -2.88657986e-16])

In [68]: data_scaled.std(axis=0)
Out[68]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Things look good up to this point!

Now I could go forward and feed this data to my model and then test with the test data (also scaled with the same scaler and fit). However, I need to be able to see exactly what prediction was given by the classifier for each `AMID`. So, I am thinking that I should either map the scaled data back to the `AMID` for each datapoint and then try each datapoint separately with the classifier's `.predict()` method or I should, somehow, map the results of `.predict()` back to the list of `AMID`.

My first thought was to assign the new values to the original dataframe, something like that:

```
In [73]: df_copy['A'] = data_scaled[:,0:1]

In [74]: df_copy
Out[74]: 
        AMID         A         B         C
0  AMID-1000 -0.660180  0.768200  0.689369
1  AMID-1001 -0.584459  0.607390  0.471788
2  AMID-1002  1.101281  0.806657  0.994664
3  AMID-1003 -1.190499  0.382427  0.894856
4  AMID-1004 -0.536992  0.712373  0.870068
5  AMID-1005  0.200213  0.691643  0.546960
6  AMID-1006  2.340942  0.169759  0.804370
7  AMID-1007  0.412372  0.686212  0.377556
8  AMID-1008 -0.659358  0.981370  0.588750
9  AMID-1009 -0.423321  0.264285  0.463403
```

But I am not sure if this would skew the association between original `'AMID'` and scaled values for each column.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `However, what I need to do is map the scaled data back to the 'AMID', so that I can record the classifier's .predict() output for each AMID value separately`Don't get it. Could you reformulate please ?

Comment: I have the ground truth for each one of the datapoints, so I can in fact evaluate the performance of the classifier just fine, even without the mapping to `AMID`. But I also need to know which specific automobile (`AMID`) belongs to which class. So I was thinking that will need to iterate through the dataset and feed each datapoint to the classifier separately. In short, I want to find out what does the classifier predict for each `AMID`. Thanks!

Comment: `I have the ground truth for each one of the datapoints`. if you have the class then what are you trying to get ? --> `But I also need to know which specific automobile (AMID) belongs to which class` ? I don't get it

Comment: @MMF I'm trying to find the best way to represent my data and therefore I evaluate the performance of the classifier against several different flavours of my dataset and see what dataset delivers the best results or allows the classifier to solve the problem more effectively. For this binary problem, I have the ground truth and therefore I can calculate the performance of each dataset flavour.

Comment: @MMF Q: `But I also need to know which specific automobile (AMID) belongs to which class`. A: What I'm trying to say is that I need to know what did the algorithm predict for each datapoint.

Comment: `set_index` would not work ?

Comment: @MMF Yes, it appears that this would work fine indeed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, I'd just set `AMID` as the index (so that it doesn't interfere and makes it easier after), and then recreate a dataframe on the go, like so:

```
df.set_index('AMID', inplace=True)
from sklearn import preprocessing
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
df

                  A         B         C
AMID                                   
AMID-1000 -0.660181  0.663739  0.095517
AMID-1001 -0.584459  0.001476 -0.987447
AMID-1002  1.101281  0.822116  1.615059
AMID-1003 -1.190499 -0.924988  1.118286
AMID-1004 -0.536990  0.433827  0.994909
AMID-1005  0.200213  0.348455 -0.613294
AMID-1006  2.340943 -1.800818  0.667911
AMID-1007  0.412372  0.326088 -1.456467
AMID-1008 -0.659357  1.541636 -0.405293
AMID-1009 -0.423322 -1.411532 -1.029181
```

You could `reset_index()` if you want `AMID` as a column instead of the index, but IMHO it's better as an index (I assume you want to fit another model on that later on...)

Comment: Tu as été plus rapide que moi ! Bien joué. Je l'avais proposé en commentaire !

Comment: Oui, Just saw that you proposed it too yeah :)